# Blazor set background color with parameter

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I have a card blazor component with css styling, i've tried to pass background color as a parameter to the styling in the following way:

```
@inject NavigationManager UriHelper

<SfCard @onclick=@Navigate CssClass="@NavigateUri">
    <CardHeader Title="@Title">
        <span class="fa fa-@CardIcon test-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardContent Content="@Content" />
</SfCard>

<style>
    .e-card .e-card-header {
        background: @CardColor;
        height: 60px;
        align-self: flex-start;
    }

</style>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string Content { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string NavigateUri { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string CardColor { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string CardIcon { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    void Navigate()
    {
        UriHelper.NavigateTo(NavigateUri);
    }
}
```

It works with 1 card, but when trying to create multiple instances of cards, like this for example:

```
    <Card Title="test1" NavigateUri="test1" CardIcon="random"
        Content="test1 content" CardColor="red">
    </Card>

    <Card Title="test2" NavigateUri="test2" CardIcon="random"
        Content="test2 content" CardColor="blue">
    </Card>
```

They are all colored with the first color provided (red) and not each with its own color

Comment: I'm confused; you set the CssClass to NavigateUri which could perhaps set a background color depending on what the `.test1` and `.test2` look like, and you have a `background:` that uses `@CardColor` that seems not to be passed. What part of the process is it you're actually using to set the bg color?

Comment: Just an FYI: Your parameter seems to be called `CardColor`, but you are setting `BackgroundColor`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you'll get away with rendering multiple different `<style` blocks that redefine the same classes, unless blazor is going to help out in isolating that CSS to just this component..

Comment: @AstridE. sorry it was a typo

Comment: @CaiusJard It is passed to "background: @CardColor;" with "CardColor="red">"

and it does work, for 1 card, but for all cards it sets same color

Comment: But, look at the resulting HTML; you'll have multiple `<style` blocks that all define the same class. What makes the browser localize the style definition to just that one card? If you make an html of `<style>p{color:red;}</style><p>Hello</p> <style>p{color:blue;}</style><p>Goodbye</p>` then all words will be blue because the second style block overwrites the first style block in the browsers memory. It's not like the "p is red" is active when hello is written so hello gets red, and then "p is blue" is active when Goodbye is written so Goobye is blue... The style dictionary is live/hotswap

Comment: Overwriting it with new entries changes everything on the page that uses the given style.. This is a cornerstone of modern app development; to be able to lay out elements with some class X and then toggle the style of X using script and have everything instantly change (light/dark mode)

Comment: @CaiusJard what would be the solution to my problem then?

Comment: @dimakal Are you positive you only want to set the background color of the card header, not the whole card (SfCard)?

Comment: use a `style=` attribute? `<CardHeader Title="@Title" style=@("background:" + @CardColor)>` (or make it a parameter of CardHeader and do it in there)

Comment: @CaiusJard Agree with your thought, but I can't see that the Syncfusion `CardHeader` can take a `style` attribute?

Comment: @AstridE. it does not unfortunately

Comment: Ah, so today's lesson - uninstall SF and use MB :D

Comment: @CaiusJard I wasn't familiar with MB, I'll give it a try, it sure does look very good

Comment: I liked it for a few reasons; it's free, looks great, the team are reasonably reachable on Discord, the docs have a good range of samples to play with and a live "try it and mess about with it" playground before you put it into a project. Also really impressed with Blazorise; their support is the best I've come across - ask in discord and get a direct answer from one of the lead devs and theyre very responsive. Can also tag blazorise here and get a quick answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Revised Answer

Something like this should work.  I've used Guids to create uniqueness in each instance of the component.  It's a manual version of component isolated CSS.

```
<div id="@UID" class="card text-white e-card mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-header e-card-header">Header</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    @css  {
        background: @CardColor;
    }

</style>

@code {
    public string UID = $"xx-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";

    private string css => $"#{UID} .e-card-header";

    [Parameter] public string CardColor { get; set; } = "#004";
}
```

Here's my test page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<MyCard CardColor="#004" />
<MyCard CardColor="#040" />
<MyCard CardColor="#800" />

@code {
}
```

And the result:

[image]

#### SyncFusion version:

Here's a "sort of working" Syncfusion version - I got fed up hoop jumping to get it fully installed!

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Cards
<SfCard id="@UID" CssClass="@NavigateUri">
    <CardHeader Title="@Title">
        <span class="fa fa-@CardIcon test-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardContent Content="@Content" />
</SfCard>

<style>
    @css {
        background: @CardColor;
    }

</style>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Hello";

    [Parameter]
    public string Content { get; set; } = "Hello Blazor";

    [Parameter]
    public string NavigateUri { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string CardColor { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string CardIcon { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string UID = $"xx-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";

    private string css => $"#{UID} .e-card-header";
}
```

And running that shows the background color changes:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i dont see how it is different from my code, and specifically my issue was with creating multiple instances of class. with 1 instance it is working

Comment: Apologies, too early to read the question fully!!  See my revised answer.

Comment: Oof, it's a bit overkill!

Comment: After using the UID i'm not getting any background color

Comment: @CaiusJard.  Personally I would manually set it in each instance of the component, but this is a way to manually create really isolated CSS.  I'm always aware that we normally only get about 20% of the information!

Comment: @dimakal.  Are you using a letter prefix to the UID?  I think ids must start with a letter.  See my revised answer with my test page and a screen shot.  I'm not using syncFusion as I don't use it.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis

I've tried it like this:
`@css {`

but I believe I need the .e-card class for it to work so I've tried this too:

`.e-card @css {`

But still nothing

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis with all these limitations with SyncFusion's card i think ill just go with making my own card with your example, so i've selected your answer. thanks

Comment: @dimakal.  I just tried to add SyncFusion to my test project to help you.  The process reminded me of why I HATE these frameworks!! See my updated answer for my Syncfusion version.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yes that did the trick for the SfCard, now it works as expected, thank you!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis This has so far been true for me 100% of the time-- that it's easier for me to make my own components than to figure out how someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the background color for the whole `SfCard`, not just the `CardHeader`, you could take advantage of the `SfCard`'s property `HtmlAttributes` ([docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Cards.SfCard.html#Syncfusion_Blazor_Cards_SfCard_HtmlAttributes)) and set the parameter-dependent `style` value directly on the `SfCard` component in your `Card` implementation.

```
<SfCard style="background-color: @CardColor">
    <!--Content-->
</SfCard>
```

Comment: It does work for whole SfCard, but i only need it for CardHeader, which it doesnt work for

Comment: Put a div inside the header then, and set it on that

Comment: I know, that's why I pointed out that it works for the whole card. Unfortunately I cannot think of options for setting it only for the header component.